# JavaScript comparing NUMBER.MIN_VALUE to 0.0 returns false

Tags: javascript, numbers, exponential

I am trying this:

```
if(0.0 > Number.MIN_VALUE){
    alert("true")
} else {
    alert("False")
}
```

Above code is returning false. Can any one explain me why this is returning false? If I compare 0.0 > -90909, it returns true.

Comment: 0 is greater than any negative numbers

Comment: Are you implicitly asking why `Number.MIN_VALUE` is positive rather than negative? Have you logged `Number.MIN_VALUE` already?

Comment: `Number.MIN_VALUE` is a positive value something like `5e-324`

Comment: The MIN_VALUE property is the number closest to 0, not the most negative number, that JavaScript can represent.

MIN_VALUE has a value of approximately 5e-324. Values smaller than MIN_VALUE ("underflow values") are converted to 0.

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MIN_VALUE]

Comment: How did this question get two upvotes? It either shows no research effort, because the value of [`Number.MIN_VALUE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MIN_VALUE) is well documented, or it is very unclear as to why the OP believes that it should return “true” (and thereby not even a useful question) and what the OP is actually trying to do — all the reasons for downvoting.

Comment: My Bad... I had an impression that MIN_Value will be negative.

Answer (score 4):

[Number.MIN_VALUE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MIN_VALUE) is the smallest positive integer representable in JavaScript, so it's going to be bigger than 0.0. What you want is probably the opposite of [Number.MAX_VALUE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_VALUE):

```
if(0.0 > -Number.MAX_VALUE){
    alert("true")
} else {
    alert("False")
}
```

But you'll have to give more details as to what you're trying to do before getting better advice.